# Finding the first unique integer in int[]

Tags: java, arrays, list, set, hashset

Given an integer array, I want to return the first unique element in the array. I used A List .contains() method to check if Integer array contains the element, the method is correct but not efficient(time complexity O(N**2)) since  List.contain() loops entire list comparing each element.

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int num = 0;
    for(int a: A){
        if(list.contains((Integer)a)){
            list.remove((Integer)a);
        }else{
          list.add(a); 
        }
       
    }

 
    num = !list.isEmpty()? (int) set.get(0): 0;
    return list.size()<1?-1:num;
}
//example input/output

int[] a = {1,2,6,1,6}

//I get the correct answer 2
```

Done my research and found that HashSet has  Contains which is  more efficient
Problem is Once i use a HashSet(I also tried Set) I dont get same result. The function should return the first unique element in the int[]

import java.util.*;

```
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
      int num = 0;
    for(int a: A){
        if(set.contains(a)){
            set.remove((Integer)a);
        }else{
          set.add(a); 
        }
       
    }
 
    num = !set.isEmpty()? (int) set.iterator.next(): 0;
    return set.isEmpty()?-1:num;
}


  //example input/output

int[] a = {1,2,6,1,6}

// Should return 2 but get the wrong  answer 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give an example of input, output, and what you expect the output to be. But also ask yourself: what's the difference between a Set and a List?

Comment: @tgdavies Edited. I know a list has ordered elements and sets have unordered elements but , what i don't understand is  why methods remove , add and contains methods  not giving same result as List , since I'm working with  specific element (not indexs).

Comment: Please edit your question to give an example of input, output, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: @tgdavies I have edited, Please review

Comment: It is not the `remove`, `add` and `contains` that matter.  It is the `next()`.  It is returning the first element of an *unordered* collection ... which is tantamount to returning a *randomly chosen* element.

Comment: But ... having said that ... the contains / add / remove logic is wrong in the `List` case too.  Consider carefully what happens if the input list contains **three** copies of `1`.

Comment: @StephenC yes but in this case The set has only one element so i want to return the only element in the set

Comment: It looks to me as though Set should work *for that specific input* (as @StephenC says it doesn't work if there's a number repeated an odd number of times)

Comment: It also won't work reliably if there are two or more unique numbers ... because of the ordering issue.

Comment: A set does not remove elements that are repeated. It just keeps one instance of all elements. I dont think a set can even achieve a solution for what u want. Use a LinkedHashMap and track the count of each element. Filter for those with count 1 and take the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `LinkedHashSet` which maintains insertion order should be used to track the  *first* unique number
2. Another `Set` is needed to keep the *duplicated* values in the input array which can be detected using the fact that `Set::add` returns `false` when the element has not been actually added to the set.  Then the duplicates array has to be removed from the set of input and the first remaining element is returned.

Also, it may be better to return `null` / `Integer` value instead of `-1` which is more appropriate for returning *an index* in the input array/list when a requested value is not found.

That being said a solution may look as follows:

```java
public static Integer firstUnique(int ... arr) {
    Set<Integer> input = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    for (int x : arr) {
        if (!input.add(x)) {
            duplicates.add(x);
        }
    }
    input.removeAll(duplicates);
    return input.isEmpty() ? null : input.iterator().next();
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(firstUnique(1, 2, 6, 1, 4, 6)); // 2
System.out.println(firstUnique(1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 2)); // null
```